# Having trouble copying files from resources to my desktop

Tags: c#

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    byte[] myfile = Properties.Resources.Test;
    File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\Users\\Christian Pacheco\\Desktop\\Excel\\AddStudent.csv", myfile);
    MessageBox.Show("CSV Template Downloaded");
    Process proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Users\\Christian Pacheco\\Desktop\\Excel\\AddStudent.csv";
    proc.Start();

    Add_Student addstud = new Add_Student();
    addstud.Show();
  }
  catch(Exception)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Failed downloading CSV file!");
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Consider reading the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make good quality and easy to understand questions.

Comment: I'm so sorry sir, I think I deleted it when I highlighted my questions :( I'm very very very sorry..

Comment: So what's the issue?  Any exceptions?

Comment: Hey @Ghost, are receiving permission issues or access issues?

Answer (score 1):

The 1st reason for the issue is that you are passing a string when the method is expecting a byte array.

1.)
This will give you a byte array to pass to FileWriteAllBytes.

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Properties.Resources.Test);
```

Making the above change should correct issue.  Hope this helps!